# 2D grease pencil layer disappears when parenting to armature bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, grease-pencil, 2d

I am following a tutorial on how to rig and animate a 2D character. I am using Blender 3.2.0. I have the character as an object consisting of several grease pencil layers. As per the tutorial I setup the armature and built all the bones. As per the tutorial I now have to parent the object's grease pencil layers to the bones. I start with the `fringe` of the hair grease pencil layer for which there is a `fringe` bone and do the following (as per the tutorial): In `Object Mode` select the object (the character) and in the Properties panel go to the grease pencil tab group and in the Layers select the `fringe` layer, then in the `Relations` settings select the `Armature` as the `Parent` and the `fringe` bone. I do this and then my `fringe` grease pencil layer disappears. I tested with the `hair` grease pencil layer and bone as well, the same thing happens. I am sure it is a silly setting or something I unknowingly did, as newbies always do, if someone can give me tips to resolve this I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: After hiding all other layers I was able to establish that the grease pencil layer is being transformed to somewhere in the middle of the character, hence I did not see it it is hidden by the other layers, so I know now it is being transformed by the parenting, but how to fix it, for grease pencil layer parenting I cannot see any way to preserve the layer's offset?

Comment: Also need to mention I did zero out (freeze) all transforms of everything.

Comment: I think I found the problem, the character is originally from an svg file imported with several curves, these are then converted to grease pencil objects and joined togehter to form the character, there is a step I missed, after converting the curves to grease pencil objects I had to zero (freeze) transforms of the grease pencil objects before joining them all in one. After joining I moved the character to the center (was not centered, well it is not semetrical character) and then had to zero out again.